# Import a layer in MySQL using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, import, mysql

I managed to import a layer from a MySQL database in QGIS with PyQGIS.

Now I'm looking to **import a layer from QGIS into MySQL**. 
I explored several ways :

1. Using **ogr2ogr on the command line**, the loading was really very very slow.
2. Using the **MySQL Importer plugin**: I looked at the script, it also uses `ogr2ogr` on the command line, the result was similar.
3. Using **PyQGIS** (although I think it uses `ogr2ogr` too). I encounter the following error:

   > Unable to load mysql data provider

My code is the following :

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
uri = "dbname='result' host=localhost port=3306 user='root' password='charlotte' key=id type=POINT table=\"result\".\"test\" (geom) sql="
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
error = QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer(layer, uri, "mysql", crs, False)
if error[0] != 0:
    iface.messageBar().pushMessage(u'Error', error[1], Qgis.Critical, 5)
```

I looked at the [documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsVectorLayerExporter.html?highlight=exportlayer#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer) which specifies that the method `QgsVectorLayerExporter.exportLayer`waits in 3rd parameter the providerKey. I tried several of them in vain.

I use QGIS 3.10.

Comment: The question is Why it is so long with `ogr2ogr` ? What is the volume and type of data ? Did you try to append records in a table or create a new one ? Maybe triggers, indexes in a DB can slow down import.

Comment: I agree with you. I'm trying to import 200,000 features (gps data) by creating a new table without triggers. Plus, I'm importing on a local server.

Comment: And how long take this import ? Is it a GPX file ? Waypoints ? Trackpoints ?

Comment: Trackpoints. About 15 minutes.

Comment: The fastest way will be to generate a SQL import script. Take a trackpoint record, make an INSERT script with 200 000 times this trackpoint to see, with MySQL executing this script, how long your local server take ?

Comment: With a script containing 200,000 INSERT INTO, it took me about 15 minutes (12,000 per hour). I'm not used to using MySQL. This slowness surprised me compared to PostGIS. Thanks for your leads.